# I have sit the TOEFL iBT for several times, Which one can I post: my most recent score or my best score?

Tags: graduate-admissions, language-exams, toefl

I know that it's possible to pass the TOEFL iBT several times. However, it has been one hour since I looked for the answer on the web, but I don't manage to know if all the scores are sent to the university I apply.

In other words, if I pass the test two times, can I send only my best score?

Comment: No.  But why would you want to?

Comment: Because I'm bad. :(

Comment: Ah.  You did worse the second time, then?

Comment: Actually, I haven't passed the TOEFL yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the only way for schools not to receive the complete record of test scores is for you to cancel the test score. Since nowadays the test scores are usually finalized once you agree to get the score, I think the answer is probably no.

Comment: I don't like this answer, but I'm afraid that it could be the right one.